# Pushing in MySQL data with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a program but I'm new to js/jQuery/Ajax. I am trying to get user input from a form (html) and send it over to a php file that will insert the data into a MySQL database and then ultimately spit out the information into a div. I press submit but my user submitted data does not get inserted into the database. I initially had the submission redirect to my php file through the  tag (action="post.php") which had worked in terms of inserting the data into the mysql database but had also redirected it to that post.php file upon submission.

my js file datawire.js:

```
$( 'button#submit').on('click', function() {
  var uName = $('input#uName').val();
  var uMessage = $('input#uMessage').val();

  if ($.trim(uName) != '' && $.trim(uMessage) != '') {
    $.post('post.php', {username: uName, message: uMessage}, function(data) {
      $('div#viewer').text(data);
    });
  }
});
```

My php file post.php

```
 <?php include("config.php");
$username = isset($_POST['username']);
$message = isset($_POST['message']);
if (($username && $message) && (empty($_POST['username'] === false) && empty($_POST['message']) === false)) {
    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // insert into database
    $nowTime = getDateTime();
    $userIp = getIp();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO commentdb (id,username, message,date,ip) VALUES ('','$username','$message', '$nowTime', '$userIp') ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);    
} 
?>
```

and my HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>        
        <!-- latest jQuery direct from google -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- for getting data -->
        <script  src="datawire.js"></script>

        <!-- for posting data -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#viewer').load("getdata.php");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="viewer">   </div>
            <br>
            <!-- User form -->
            <form method='post'>
            <input type="text" id="uName" name="username" placeholder="Name" value="" maxlength="15" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="uMessage" name="message" placeholder="Message" value="" maxlength="100" />
            <br />
            <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit!</button> <button type="reset">Clear!</button>
            </form>           
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you any errors in browser's console? What browser you use?

Comment: Your SQL is unsafe. You're putting request data directly in your SQL string without escaping, allowing for injection attacks. You should also being using `mySQLi` or `PDO` for database connectivity as the `mysql_` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

Comment: There were no errors in my browser's console.
@PaparazzoKid - I replaced mysql_ with mysqli after your advice. For the request data part without escaping, are you trying to say add a mysqli_close($connection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the contents of datawire.js with $(document).ready like you did in html file.  This insures $ is actually defined before it's used.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent your form submit with preventDefault() function

```
$( 'button#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var uName = $('input#uName').val();
    var uMessage = $('input#uMessage').val();

    if ($.trim(uName) != '' && $.trim(uMessage) != '') {
        $.post('post.php', {username: uName, message: uMessage}, function(data) {
            $('div#viewer').text(data);
         });
     }
});
```

Return the text message from the server like this

```
<?php include("config.php");
$username = isset($_POST['username']);
$message = isset($_POST['message']);
if (($username && $message) && (empty($_POST['username'] === false) && empty($_POST['message']) === false)) {
    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // insert into database
    $nowTime = getDateTime();
    $userIp = getIp();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO commentdb (id,username, message,date,ip) VALUES ('','$username','$message', '$nowTime', '$userIp') ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);    

   if($result)
   {
    echo " Data Inserted Successfully";
   }else{
    echo " Data insert failed - ".mysql_error();
   }
}else{

  echo " Required fields are missing";

} 
?>
```